# Linux file write page buffer and multi threading CPU cache

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading

Is data written by one thread to a FD, immediately available to another thread ?
Below is the C++ code to explain the question.

Operating System = Red Hat Linux

File open code

```
//Below are global variables
int fileFd_A = open(fileName_A, O_RDWR | O_CREAT, S_IREAD | S_IWRITE | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH);
int fileFd_B = open(fileName_B, O_RDWR | O_CREAT, S_IREAD | S_IWRITE | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH);

std::atomic<int64_t> lastFileAPos = {-1};
std::atomic<int64_t> lastFileBPos = {-1};

const int WriteSz = 16;
```

File writing done in Writer thread (posix)

```
//Below called in a loop
int64_t fileAPosition  = tell(fileFd_A);
int64_t fileBPosition  = tell(fileFd_B);

write(fileFd_A , pBufA, WriteSz);
write(fileFd_B , pBufB, WriteSz);//Assume all writes are successful

lastFileAPos.store(fileAPosition , std::memory_order_relaxed);
lastFileBPos.store(fileBPosition , std::memory_order_relaxed);
```

File reading done in a different posix thread,

```
//Below called in a loop (assume lastFileAPos/lastFileBPos == -1 case filtered out out before calling below)
int readSzA = pread(fileFd_A, bufferA, WriteSz, (off_t)lastFileAPos.load(std::memory_order_relaxed));
int readSzB = pread(fileFd_B, bufferB, WriteSz, (off_t)lastFileBPos.load(std::memory_order_relaxed));
```

Now is it possible that reader thread NOT being able to read latest data written at lastFileAPos or/and lastFileBPos in some iterations ?
i.e either readSzA < WriteSz or readSzB < WriteSz (or both) ?
Is it possible that readSzA  < WriteSz and readSzB == WriteSz ?

my feeling is that due to some of the writes being in write thread CPU cache (which still not sent to main memory), reader thread CPUs might not be able to read them immediately (So some of the reads could
fail).
If this is the case (i.e. some reads could fail), will using memory_order_release(for store) and memory_order_acquire(for load) instead of memory_order_relaxed resolve this issue ?
i.e. calling "lastFileAPos.load(std::memory_order_acquire)" will ensure ALL memory writes(including writes to kernel write buffer) before "lastFileAPos.store(fileAPosition , std::memory_order_release)" are  visible. So it is guaranteed that readSzA == WriteSz and readSzB == WriteSz

Comment: Why do you use the file to communicate with two threads? I don't see any benefit.

Comment: The general rule with POSIX file I/O is that if you can prove that the `write` system call returned before the call to `read` was made, then you will read the new data: the file caches are system-wide, not per-process/thread/CPU.  The danger here is that in theory, your relaxed stores may be reordered before the `write` call.  I'd be surprised if that can happen on any real-life system: the compiler can't reorder access around a function whose workings it doesn't know, and a system call trap should be an effective memory barrier.

Comment: But yes, using release/acquire semantics should avoid even any theoretical problems.

Comment: @NateEldredge, I can make lastFileAPos.store to be dependent upon the return value of write call. So re-ordering problem can be solved (I guess you meant same/similar by "system call trap"). Do you have an idea/reference how POSIX compliant Linux OSs implement this ? Do they skip writing to CPU caches for write calls ? Also Not sure if Red-Hat Linux is POSIX compliant in this case.

Comment: They have a lock of some kind on the kernel's buffer / page cache, which has acquire/release barriers so that the next process to take the lock is guaranteed to see all the data that was written before the previous process released the lock.  It's not a matter of "skip writing to CPU caches" - most of these systems have coherent caches so that is not the issue, it's about reordering of loads and stores before they ever hit the cache in the first place.  (It seems to be a common misconception that memory ordering problems are mainly to do with caching.)

Comment: You can be assured that any modern Unix-like system is going to have this behavior with respect to read/write, whether it claims full POSIX compliance or not.  A system that didn't would be unusable.

Comment: @NateEldredge, I am currently running a test to verify this (1 billion iterations). Of course only a negative confirmation can be obtained with any amount of testing. You can post yours as the answer. I will accept it after the test completion.